# Page.pagename OOPS Concept

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagereference

We use `Page.pagename` to get the Page Reference of a Visual Force Page.
I am unable to get the OOPS concept related to Page.pagename

Here

1. Page is a class?
2. pagename is a static variable?

What is this? How can I get the Page Reference using `Page.custompagename` of a custom page(custompagename) created ?

Answer (score 2):

`Page.PageName` is a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) for `PageReference` objects that sets the URL to the appropriate value for the Visualforce page that matches the name. The platform verifies that the page name exists when the Apex is compiled so this mechanism works for any Visualforce page.

You can see that independent PageReferences are created by e.g. running this in the developer console:

```
PageReference pr1 = Page.PageName;
pr1.getParameters().put('abc', 'def');
System.debug('>>> ' + pr1.getParameters());

PageReference pr2 = Page.PageName;
pr2.getParameters().put('123', '456');
System.debug('>>> ' + pr2.getParameters());
```

Comment: Can you please explain me 'factory' in terms of apex / visualforce ????

Comment: @TusharArora As the factory link I included explains, a factory is something that creates instances of objects. (Its a general programming concept; there is nothing special about its use in Apex.) So while Page.PageName might look like it provides a reference to one object, in fact it creates a new object each time it is used and each of those objects is an instance of a [PageReference](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_system_pagereference.htm).